# Replace pipe with comma except between curly braces in CSV in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Need some solution to replace pipe with comma in specific column of CSV file, which is also having some key value as pipe separated strings (could be any in number, one or more).

Basically need to replace pipe which is not within curly braces i.e.{subStringX441|subStringX442|subStringX443|subStringX444} should remain untouched.

Can't use simple `sed -i -e 's\|\,\g' filename` as it will replace all pipes.

**Input:**

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7

stringX1,stringX2,stringX3,stringX41|stringX42|stringX43|stringX44={subStringX441|subStringX442|subStringX443|subStringX444}|stringX45,stringX5,stringX6,stringX7

stringY1,stringY2,stringY3,stringY41|stringY42|stringY43|stringY44={subStringY441|subStringY442|subStringY443}|stringY45,stringY5,stringY6,stringY7
```

**Desired Output:**

```
column1,column2,column3,column4a,column4b,column4c,column4d,column4e,column5,column6,column7

stringX1,stringX2,stringX3,stringX41,stringX42,stringX43,stringX44={subStringX441|subStringX442|subStringX443|subStringX444},stringX45,stringX5,stringX6,stringX7

stringY1,stringY2,stringY3,stringY41,stringY42,stringY43,stringY44={subStringY441|subStringY442|subStringY443},stringY45,stringY5,stringY6,stringY7
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. May I suggest that you take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)?

Comment: The usual solution would be to employ a CSV parser, but your example data don't really look like valid CSV. Hence you would have to define first how a _column_ in your data is identified. Perhaps an awk solution would be more appropriate, but without knowing more about your data, it is hard to recommend a reliable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\({[^}]*\)\||/,\1/g;s/,{/{/;1s/column4/&a,&b,&c,&d,&e/' input_file
column1,column2,column3,column4a,column4b,column4c,column4d,column4e,column5,column6,column7

stringX1,stringX2,stringX3,stringX41,stringX42,stringX43,stringX44={subStringX441|subStringX442|subStringX443|subStringX444},stringX45,stringX5,stringX6,stringX7

stringY1,stringY2,stringY3,stringY41,stringY42,stringY43,stringY44={subStringY441|subStringY442|subStringY443},stringY45,stringY5,stringY6,stringY7
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions (in strict sense) are not enough for dealing with balanced bracket (last imply at least Chomsky Type-2). I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
stringY1,stringY2,stringY3,stringY41|stringY42|stringY43|stringY44
{subStringY441|subStringY442|subStringY443}|stringY45,stringY5,stringY6,stringY7
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT=".";OFS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){if($i=="{"){inside=1};if($i=="}"){inside=0};if(!inside && $i=="|"){$i=","}};print}' file.txt
```

output

```
stringY1,stringY2,stringY3,stringY41,stringY42,stringY43,stringY44
{subStringY441|subStringY442|subStringY443},stringY45,stringY5,stringY6,stringY7
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that any single character is to be treated as field using `FPAT` variable and output field seperator is empty string using `OFS` variable. For every line I go through subsequent fields (i.e. characters) using `for` loop, if character is `{` then I set variable `inside` to `1`, if character is `}` then I set variable to `0`, then if we are not (`!`) inside and (`&&`) character is `|` change it to `,`. After processing all characters in line I `print`.

**DISCLAIMER** this solution assumes that curly brackets are never nested and every `{` has matching `}` in given line.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed  ':a;s/\({[^|}]*\)|\([^}]*}\)/\1\n\2/g;ta;y/\n|/|,/' file
```

Replace `|`'s between `{...}`'s with newlines, then translate newlines to `|`'s and `|`'s to `,`'s.